# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings eeror

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'am upgrading a project (Spring 4 -> Spring 5, Spring Boot 1 -> Spring Boot 2).
I have the following error

```
org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:57)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am currently using

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
testImplementation project(":test")
```

And there was no such error in Spring 4. I have a new library `org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.0.0` that I **did not have** in Spring 4 , I suppose this is the issue? But I don't know how to remove this ? Can somebody help ?

**PLEASE NOTE** !
I **want** to keep using my current mockito version 1.10.19. Do not advice to remove this dependency and let spring-boot-starter to take care, because then I will need to re-write all the tests. I already try this and this is not a solution in my case.

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test` that gets resolved when you compile your project?

You can also check the dependency graph by using the `project-report` plugin (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/project_report_plugin.html) to verify what version of mockito is used (i.e. is it overridden?)

`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test` versions `2.x` use Mockito `2.x`, as you can see here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.0.0.RELEASE

If you want to override the Mockito version that is used, you can try excluding the dependency that comes along with `spring-boot-starter-test` by doing

```
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:{your version here}') {
            exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-core'
            force = true
        }
```

Because you are forcing a `major version downgrade` for a component, you can expect to have incompatibility issues during runtime, depending on how you use the test libraries.

Comment: Nope. No result at all, I excluded using your approach mockito-core and result is the same. My call stack still goes to org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset,java where cannot solve the MockingDetails (interface) getMockCreationSettings() method. Which is CRAZY since MockingDetails is a MOCKITO CLASS ! I feel desperate.

Comment: Like I said, you can expect to have incompatibility issues during runtime (i.e. when running your test). In fact, you are having such issues: the newer `spring-boot-starter-test` relies internally on newer calls to `mockito`, but you are supplying an **older** version of `mockito` for compile and runtime. Looking at the stacktrace, the test failed because Spring is looking for the `org.mockito.MockingDetails#getMockCreationSettings()` method, but that method is introduced in `mockito 2.1.0` (see https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/main/src/main/java/org/mockito/MockingDetails.java)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this thread: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1394 I excluded mockito-all dependency and solved my issue

```
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
```